# FP-Growth cannot processing

Tags: r, fpgrowth

I have a problem processing the fp-growth algorithm on Rstudio
this is my first time using R

I write code

```
FpgConf = rCBA :: fpgrowth (dataset, support = 0.1, confidence = 0.5, maxLength = 2, consequent = "Species", parallel = FALSE)
```

en then system responds like this

> Error in dimnames (x) <- dn:
> length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

please tell me how the solution
*sorry my english not good*

[this my data transactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o07VI.png)

Comment: Could you edit your questions by copy-pasting your data in the question by running ```dput(dataset)``` in the console (copy-paste the console output)?

Comment: My guess is your 'dataset' object does not contain the variable 'Species'.  Sounds like 'Species' is from the 'iris' dataset, which is used with examples in the FpConf documentation.  But you're probably using different data. So you probably need to adjust the ```consequent``` argument in ```rCBA```.  Have a look at the help file '?CBA :: fpgrowth'.

Comment: I'm sorry. That's not quite what we need. 1) Run ```dput(dataset)```. 2) Copy the output you see in the console, 3) Click on the 'edit' button' below your question. 4) paste the console output into the text of the question and 5) click save.